# Modifying JSON variable name Struts 2

Tags: java, json, struts2, annotations, struts2-json-plugin

I have a pre defined json that has the following variable assigned to a JSON Object:

```
{
    ....
    "class": "P"
    ....
}
```

Trouble is, I'm using the Struts 2 JSON plugin and the following code:

```
private String class
```

is not allowed, since class is a reserved keyword. Does anyone know of a way to override the variable names in Struts 2's JSON plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `getClass()` instead, also there's `@JSON` annotation where you can specify name.

Comment: Beautiful, @JSON(name="class") over the setter worked. Thanks